# How to add rigidbody to a imported gameobject of a modeling software?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have imported a gameobject in my game which I created in a 3d modeling software. Now I would like control the movement of that gameobject so that as soon as it hits another gameobject it should stop his movement.

I have read that for this a gameobject needs a rigidbody. So how and where in the script can I add a rigidbody to that gameobject?

Comment: When you have a gameobject in your scene, you can add the rigidbogy as every other component, by just adding it to the list of components. Or, if you like, create and add it in code. Everything standard.

Comment: it is quite awful that you would ask this basic question about unity without even making an effort to search for the answer yourself. This is basically the first thing any tutorial will teach you. -1 from me, even tho I never like to downvote.

Comment: I know how to add it with the GUI but I did not know it how to add it to all my clones of game objects I created by script.

Comment: @sportente Have your clones a MonoBehavior Object attached?

Comment: I created an empty game object and added my script for creating my clones to this empty game object. However, in the script the created game object is hidden.

Comment: @sportente Please show us your script. That's were your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Conclusion**

This is really a 101 Unity3D Question.

Please have a look at the excellent tutorials on www.unity3d.com before asking questions like this here at SO. There is a own [Rigidbodies](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/rigidbody?playlist=17120) section for handling this. With clear examples, video tutorials and source code (*Heart, what do you want more?*).

---

**Short explanation (EDITOR)**

Drag you Model into the Editor Scene.

Select the GameObject with the name of your Model in the hierarchy.

Click on `Add Component` and choose `Ridigbody`.

[image: Select Ridigbody]

---

**Even shorter explanation (CODE)**

Just this simple Line of code:

`myGameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();`

---

**Cloned Objects**

An example for instantiating `GameObjects` in a `for-loop` and adding an `Rigidbody` to them.

```
Rigidbody currentRb;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    GameObject clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    currentRb = clone.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
    // You can even access the rigidbody with no effort
    currentRb.detectCollisions = true;
}
```

---

**Attached to MonoBehavoir**

There is a Attribute for your MonoBehavior objects named `RequireComponent()`.

Copied from the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html), this attachment will add to every object a Rigidbody component.

```
// The GameObject requires a Rigidbody component
[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void FixedUpdate()  {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your well explained answer. I will try that now.

Comment: However, as soon as I press play I see an existing rigidbody but I can move my game object through all the clones even if I set the speed to zero as soon as they touch the other game objects... hm=(

Comment: @sportente This isn't what you asked for. You have to look up `Colliders` to understand why an Object can pass through another. Please mark this Question as correct for the next readers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for asking so many things. I am a beginner and I have to create a game which is for me quite difficult. I recognized that when I use the OnCollision function that this happens not every frame... however in my game I would need this because I produce a sinewave with the clones which has to be followed with a ring without touching it... is there an option?

Comment: @sportente As i mention, start with looking up Unity3D's own tutorials. This will really help you understand all this things. Here at SO you are at the completely wrong place as beginner. StackOverflow is for specific problems not basic question or learning coding.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. I already watched tutorials of Unity... believe me. The problem I have is that when I set the speed to zero as soon as my ring collides with a game object it is stucked and I can not move it to the other direction... I searched now for 2 hours without any solution.. =(

Comment: @sportente Can you upload your Source Code on GitHub or BitBucket? I need to look at the whole project to debug this.

Comment: I created now an account in GitHub. How can I load up code? Thank you already in advance for your help. I really appreciate it!
Edit: I followed you on GitHub.

Comment: Just upload it there, i will fork the whole thing.

Comment: Ok, I will do that in about an hour. Thank you very much! It is very nice that there are some people like you who understand beginners as I am one of them...

Comment: Mkey! I also recommed SourceTree for handling git Repositiories.

Comment: So I upload the script for my ring which I have from a 3d modeling software. Can you see it?

Comment: Yes, i'll check it out at home.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw that your mother tongue is german on your profile. So you can answer me in German if you like...=) 
If you should need my email is:
sportente123@gmail.com

Comment: E-Mails don't work in SO. Just go to my Homepage form my profil and write me.